# Total precache size is about 0 B for 0 resources

Tags: sw-precache

With grunt-sw-precache, I am trying to cache my application:

```
'develop': {
        // staticFileGlobs: [
        //   'app/styles/**/*.css',
        //   'font/**/*.{woff,ttf,svg,eot}',
        //   'app/images/**/*.{gif,png,jpg}',
        //   'app/scripts/**/*.js',
        // ],
        staticFileGlobs: ['index.html','/app/**/*.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif}'],
        stripPrefix: 'app',
        baseDir:'./',
        runtimeCaching: [{
          handler: 'networkFirst'
        }]
      },
    },
```

I always get:

```
Total precache size is about 0 B for 0 resources.
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
  projectRoot
      ______app
         __________images
         __________styles
         __________controllers
             __________jsFilesHere
             ___________app.js
             _____________config.js
             _____________index.html
             _____________sw.js
```

I need to cache all my files to enable the application to run offline as well.
For that matter I need to cache my entire app folder

How do I change this

staticFileGlobs: ['index.html','/app/**/*.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif}'],

to be able to get this working?

I tried replacing it with:

staticFileGlobs: ['*.*'] as well. but yet I get the same message.

As suggested, I am now storing sw.js in app folder only and have removed `/`

```
 'develop': {
        navigateFallback: '/index.html',   
        staticFileGlobs: ['scripts/**/*.js'],
        stripPrefix: 'app',
        baseDir:'./app',
        runtimeCaching: [{
          handler: 'networkFirst'
        }]
      },
```

But still nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

All glob patterns are interpreted with the current working directory as the base by default. The two patterns you're using are:

- `index.html`, but there's no `index.html` in your current working directory as per the directory listing your shared.
- `/app/**/*.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif}`, which should not include the leading `/` character.

Try removing the leading `/` character from your wildcard glob pattern, and figure out why your `index.html` isn't showing up in your output directory, and that will hopefully resolve the issue for you.

(I'm not sure what `baseDir: './'` signifies, as that's not one of the [supported options](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache#options-parameter) for `sw-precache`.)